# How can I get the json of a selection in a webpage?

Tags: python, json

For example, we have a webpage with a table filled with numbers. We know that there is json that contains the data we want. We open the specific webpage in a browser and select the first number of the first column.

Below are the specific site url and its json url:

- [site url](http://praktoreio.pamestoixima.gr/el/web/guest/print-retail?dateIsSet=false&currentDrawNumber=13&sportId=s-441)
- [json url](http://praktoreio.pamestoixima.gr/web/services/rs/iFlexBetting/retail/games/15104/0.json?shortTourn=true&startDrawNumber=13&endDrawNumber=13&sportId=s-441&marketIds=0&marketIds=0A&marketIds=1&marketIds=69&marketIds=68&marketIds=20&marketIds=21&marketIds=8&locale=gr&brandId=defaultBrand&channelId=0)

Can I see where in the json is the specific value ? Which key it corresponds to ?

Something similar to "View Selection Source" when you select something in a browser, but for json.

Comment: What? Are you asking how to convert arbitrary HTML to some JSON representation? How?

Comment: have you tried `request` lib?

Comment: For reading json, I use requests or pd.read_json.

Answer (score 0):

run `pip install requests`, then

```
import request
json = request.get('http://example.com').json()
```

if what you are requesting returns json, then above will work
if not, then you have to take string format and create you rown json

```
text = request.get('http://example.com').text
json = magically_turn_into_json(text)
```

Comment: I don't know if he is requesting on something that returns json, OR something that returns html....so vague

Comment: I am looking for something like "View Selection Source", just to help me identify the key in json I need.

Comment: @evil_inside you're just repeating yourself. still unclear. what is the website url

Comment: I added the website url. I am not looking for how to read the json or how to find keys or values.

Comment: the url is `http://praktoreio.pamestoixima.gr/web/services/rs/iFlexBetting/config/15104/0.json?type=sport&locale=gr&brandId=defaultBrand&channelId=0`

Comment: I have updated my question with the site url and the json url.